# Is it possible to disable formula evaluation when modifying a workbook containing macros with Apache POI?

Tags: java, vba, excel

I have an `xlsm` file which contains a VisualBasic function which is called from some cells in the workbook like this:

```
=myfunc(A1)
```

I know that if I modify Excel files with POI which contain macros and controls for them (like buttons) POI won't touch them and won't throw exceptions but when I try to modify a file which uses VB functions as formulas I get the following exception:

```
org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParseException: Name 'myfunc' is completely unknown in the current workbook
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.function(FormulaParser.java:920)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.parseNonRange(FormulaParser.java:558)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.parseRangeable(FormulaParser.java:429)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.parseRangeExpression(FormulaParser.java:268)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.parseSimpleFactor(FormulaParser.java:1119)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.percentFactor(FormulaParser.java:1079)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.powerFactor(FormulaParser.java:1066)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.Term(FormulaParser.java:1426)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.additiveExpression(FormulaParser.java:1526)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.concatExpression(FormulaParser.java:1510)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.comparisonExpression(FormulaParser.java:1467)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.unionExpression(FormulaParser.java:1447)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.parse(FormulaParser.java:1568)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.parse(FormulaParser.java:176)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell.setFormula(XSSFCell.java:444)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell.setCellFormula(XSSFCell.java:424)
    at net.sf.jett.transform.SheetTransformer.replaceFormulas(SheetTransformer.java:336)
    at net.sf.jett.transform.ExcelTransformer.replaceFormulas(ExcelTransformer.java:929)
    at net.sf.jett.transform.ExcelTransformer.postTransformation(ExcelTransformer.java:720)
    at net.sf.jett.transform.ExcelTransformer.transform(ExcelTransformer.java:411)
    at net.sf.jett.transform.ExcelTransformer.transform(ExcelTransformer.java:384)
...
...
```

My idea is to configure POI to ignore (don't evaluate) these cells. Is this possible somehow?

Comment: Maybe this post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16726832/is-it-possible-to-ignore-an-exception) in SO can help you...